# Ruby on Rails difference between get :home and static_pages_home_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am reading Ruby on Rails Tutorial (Ch 3.3.2) by Michael Hartl. 
I am currently making a failing test(RED) However, I just noticed that his static_pages_controller_test.rb has

```
test "should get home" do
  get :home
  assert_response :success
end
```

and mine has although I followed everything he did.

```
test "should get home" do
         get static_pages_home_url
         assert_response :success  
 end
```

It seems like get :home is the same as get static_pages_home_url.

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 0):

It does the same in this situation, but not in all situations.

since `get :home` is inside of your `static_pages_controller_test.rb` it looks in that controller automatically and finds the `home method`.

`get static_pages_home_url` is more dynamical. It looks for the `home url` inside of your `static_pages_controller`.

So you can call `get_static_pages_home_url` in tests on different locations but you can't with `get :home`.